# A problem occurred configuring project ':device_info_plus'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I have two projects located on my desktop; when I run flutter build apk on the two, one builds successfully while the other fails. I have really searched for the solution but couldn't get any.

I have deleted the Andriod folder and ran 'flutter create .' to update any outdated file but it's still not working.

Please does any one know what is wrong?

See the generated error below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':device_info_plus'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':device_info_plus:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :device_info_plus
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.0/gradle-8.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.0/gradle-8.2.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':device_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':device_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            3.3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)